# How to add/remove class inside div tag in range with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some `html tags` I have named class `hidecontent` to hide the element. Here I also have an element which if I click will trigger `show / hide` div element which contains data.

My data :

```
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_0">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_1">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_2">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_3">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_4">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_5">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_6">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_7">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_8">Blablablabla</div>
```

My Link :

```
<a href="#" id="data_1">Data 1</a>
<a href="#" id="data_2">Data 2</a>
<a href="#" id="data_3">Data 3</a>
```

How good would it be if my `Data 1` link `click` will display data div which has id `only` data_0, data_1, data_2 which I will use :

```
$("div").addClass("hidecontent");
$("div").removeClass("col-md-4 hidecontent").addClass("col-md-4");
```

Then for `Data 2` I will display data only from 3-5

Then for `Data 3` I will display data only from 6-8

Do I have to write one by one? Or can I use range? For example from data 0 to 2?

Thanks

Comment: can you amend the html? for example, change to `div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_1"`

Comment: Hi @SudarpoChong Yes... I can

Comment: i think u can use [css pseudo_classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assign class name to your divs
- Bind click event and read the ID
- Show/hide div class

```js
$(".trigger").on("click", function(e) {
  
  var sourceId = $(this).attr("id");
  var divToToggle = "." + sourceId;
  // console.log( sourceId );
  
  // hide all first
  $(".col-md-4").addClass("hidecontent");
  
  $(divToToggle).removeClass("hidecontent");
  
  // checking is no longer necessary if all is already hidden
  // if ($(divToToggle).hasClass("hidecontent")) {
  //   $(divToToggle).removeClass("hidecontent");
  // }
  // else {
  //   $(divToToggle).addClass("hidecontent");
  // }
  
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.hidecontent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="trigger" id="data_1">Data 1</a>
<a href="#" class="trigger" id="data_2">Data 2</a>
<a href="#" class="trigger" id="data_3">Data 3</a>

<hr/>

<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_1" content="#data_0">1 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_1" content="#data_1">1 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_1" content="#data_2">1 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_2" content="#data_3">2 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_2" content="#data_4">2 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_2" content="#data_5">2 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_3" content="#data_6">3 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_3" content="#data_7">3 Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent data_3" content="#data_8">3 Blablablabla</div>
```

Comment: Yeaahh....It's almost like I want ... Only if the Data 2 link is clicked, it not only displays data 2, but hides all data from another link

Comment: I modif your code, only use `$("div").addClass("hidecontent");` and `$(divToToggle).removeClass("hidecontent");` First, add `all div` tag with class `hidecontent` and then removeClass from divToToggle

Comment: I edited the answer. `$(".col-md-4").addClass("hidecontent");`

Comment: Why make alot of changes to the html, when you can easy make it work without?

Comment: IMHO, I guess for code readability. For novice like me, it's easier to read this kind of codes.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution:

```
            $("a").click(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                $("div[content=#" + id + ']').toggleClass("myclass");
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for your. Note it's without changing any part of your code.

It will calculate the correct number for your links to show the correct divs.

```
$("a[id^=data_]").click(function() {
  $("div.hidecontent").hide()
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("data_","");
  var start = parseInt(id) == 1 ? 0 : (parseInt(id) * 3) - 3;
  var end = parseInt(id) == 0 ? 3 : parseInt(id) * 3;
  $("div.hidecontent").slice(start, end).show();
})
```

```js
$("a[id^=data_]").click(function() {
  $("div.hidecontent").hide()
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("data_", "");
  var start = parseInt(id) == 1 ? 0 : (parseInt(id) * 3) - 3;
  var end = parseInt(id) == 0 ? 3 : parseInt(id) * 3;
  $("div.hidecontent").slice(start, end).show();
})
```

```css
.hidecontent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_0">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_1">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_2">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_3">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_4">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_5">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_6">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_7">Blablablabla</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidecontent" content="#data_8">Blablablabla</div>


<a href="#" id="data_1">Data 1</a>
<a href="#" id="data_2">Data 2</a>
<a href="#" id="data_3">Data 3</a>
```

Comment: When you click "Data_3", you are supposed to show only 6-8. It's showing 3-8 now ?

Comment: @SudarpoChong Updated